# Point Of Presence vs. Central Office

Tags: telephony, service-provider

What is the difference between these two (in distance and function)?  I understand that a Central Office is a place where the ISP stores equipment that connects many clients. But the POP has a similar definition.  It is a place where many clients connect and there are multiple POP's for each ISP.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. Central Offices and ISPs are unrelated. Central office is a telephony term. ISPs related to Internet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> What is the difference between this two (in distance and function).

*Short answer*:

- Distances - not very much, these days
- Function - Basic / Enhanced 911 is still processed through the Central Office; however other [CLECs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_local_exchange_carrier) can trunk customers' 911 calls back to the [Public Service Answering Point (PSAP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-safety_answering_point) via the local Central Office... I also think [Intrado](http://www.intrado.com/) has equipment for [CLECs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_local_exchange_carrier) to provide 911 services...

*Long answer*:

The differences between them have much more to do with historical context...

- Central Office is a term that has deep roots in the [Bell companies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_System), where the Central Office also called a [telephone exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_exchange).  Originally they housed circuit-switching technologies; these days they have similar routers and switches as you'll see in a [Point of Presence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_presence).  Telephone copper pairs star out of the Central Office to normally about 15,000-18,000 feet; however, you can also star the copper out from a [DLC can](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_loop_carrier) to cover a much larger area, because the DLCs can be connected via fiber.  The key points to remember:

  1. Because the Central Office is associated with the [Bell companies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_System), they are heavily regulated by the government.  Incumbent carriers in many other countries are also regulated in a similar manner.
  2. Construction and installations within a Central Office normally comply with Telecordia standards, such as [GR-63 NEBS](http://telecom-info.telcordia.com/site-cgi/ido/docs.cgi?ID=SEARCH&DOCUMENT=GR-63?).  NEBS-compliant equipment is a big deal to RBOCs and incumbents... NEBS requires routers / switches to have front-to-back cooling and other features that comply with Telecordia's requirements.
  3. They always have responsibility for maintaining last-mile transport to customers.
  4. Basic / Enhanced 911 is routed through the Central Office
  5. Most of the labor is unionized.
- [Point of Presence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_presence) does not always carry the same loaded meaning that Central Office does.  Most of the time, it refers to a building that is carefully selected to host internet circuits between various carriers.  Customer connectivity to a Point of Presence these days is usually over [Metro ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_Ethernet) or [SONET rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_optical_networking).

  1. These facilities are often not regulated by the government.
  2. Construction and installations don't need to comply with Telecordia standards, such as [GR-63 NEBS](http://telecom-info.telcordia.com/site-cgi/ido/docs.cgi?ID=SEARCH&DOCUMENT=GR-63?)
  3. The carriers within a POP often are *not* associated with the remains of the original [Bell companies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_System), and they are not required to host last-mile transport to a customer (although they often do). It's quite common for the local AT&T / Verizon / other bellco to offer [T-carrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-carrier) services from a POP because they will co-locate within the POP to spoon as much transport business as they can from the other carriers who might need last-mile transport to customers.
  4. POPs don't have to handle 911
  5. Labor might not be unionized.