# What does the local exchange do for the internet

Tags: internet, isp

Bit of a newbie question, but what exactly does the telephone exchange do for the internet?

Is this where the packets that leave your router go to, to connect to your isp?

Comment: Also see [Point of Presence vs Central Office](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2762/point-of-presence-vs-central-office/2763#2763)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The telephone system is only involved in internet connectivity when the copper telephone lines are used for a DSL line. At the user's end the copper line goes into a splitter that separates the phone frequencies from the DSL frequencies. The phone signal goes to a plain phone and the DSL signal goes to a DSL modem. The same happens in the local telephone exchange. The signal is split and the phone signal goes to the classical telephone system. The DSL signal goes to a DSLAM (Digital Subscriber Line Access Multiplexer). Depending on the rules/laws/customs of the country this DSLAM is operated by one or more ISPs, the incumbent phone operator or specialised DSL operators. It might be that there are DSLAMs of multiple operators in the local telephone exchange station.

Comment: And after the DSLAM, what happens to the IP packet?

Comment: There is some backhaul network. It might be layer-2 or later-3. Packets might get tunnelled. It all depends on the network architecture. At some point the packets get routed :)